# collision detection using createjs

Tags: collision-detection, createjs

I am a complete novice in createjs and wanted some guidance over this topic of collision detection. I have created some text objects using font awesome using a loop. Next I saved them in variable `objx` as `id` along with updating its position coordinates`(x,y)` in it. And here is the code for collision detection:

```
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", function(){
    var jx,jy,jt,t;
        for(var i = 0 ; i < objx.length-1 ; i++)objx[i].id.color="#8B0000";
        for(var i = 0 ; i < objx.length-1 ; i++){
            x = objx[i].x;y = objx[i].y;t = objx[i].id;
            for(var j = i+1 ; j < objx.length-1 ; j++){
                jx = objx[j].x;jy = objx[j].y;
                if(x+t.getMeasuredWidth()>=jx && y+t.getMeasuredHeight()>=jy )
                {
                    jt = objx[j].id;
                    jt.color="#0000CD";
                    t.color="#0000CD";
                }
            }
        }
        stage.update();});
  }


}
```

The initial part of tweenjs is working fine. I just wanted the collision to occur in such a way such that color of text changes only on collision and should be back to initial color after collision. This generates an image which is similar to :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is very good for EaselJS collision detection.
[Collision Detection](https://github.com/olsn/Collision-Detection-for-EaselJS)

You could use either pixel perfect detection or The bounding box collision detection.

Comment: I just started using it on a project and it is great!

Comment: Cool.If you want any more techniques contact with me . I know abount AABB colision and rotated rectangle collision. Also dont for get to tick the answer if it works !!!  :)