# How to show object when another object pass over it

Tags: javascript, createjs, tween

I'm creating an animation with 5 objects using createjs and tween.

The first object is a car that cross horizontally the screen and the other 4 objects are 4 buildings that I want to show once at a time every time the car pass over the object (that is initially hidden).

This is part of the code where i set the position and the alpha to 0.

Truck is the object crossing the screen blocks are the building I want to show one at time.

```
truck = new createjs.Shape();
truck = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult("truck"));
truck.x=-truck.image.width;
truck.y=0;
createjs.Tween.get(truck, { loop: true })
    .wait(250)
    .to({ x: w }, 5600, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(0.5));
block1 = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult("block3"));
block1.x=0;
block1.y=truck.image.height-block1.image.height;
block1.alpha=0.0;
createjs.Tween.get(block1, { override: true })
    .wait(250)
    .to({ alpha: 1 }, 600, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(0.5));
block2 = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult("block2"));
block2.x=0;
block2.y=truck.image.height-block2.image.height-block1.image.height;
block2.alpha=0.0;
createjs.Tween.get(block2, { override: true })
    .wait(500)
    .to({ alpha: 1 }, 1600, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(0.5));
block3 = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult("block1"));
block3.x=block1.image.width;
block3.y=truck.image.height-block3.image.height;;
block3.alpha=0.0;
block4 = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult("block4"));
block4.x=block1.image.width+block3.image.width;
block4.y=truck.image.height-block4.image.height;;
block4.alpha=0.0;
block5 = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult("block5"));
block5.x=block1.image.width+block3.image.width+block4.image.width;
block5.y=truck.image.height-block5.image.height;;
block5.alpha=0.0;
```

Comment: Please explain what you are asking for help with - so far all you described is what you want to happen, not what is failing or what the symptoms are.

Comment: I don't know how to implement it. At the moment I'm just putting a wait function to the blocks before appearing trying to synch the event with the truck passing over the coordinates of the block. I want to know if there is a neat way to set the alpha of an object when another object is crossing its coordinate

Comment: oh ok, so like collision detection. Check out this other contextjs question and answers, maybe will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950618/collision-detection-using-createjs

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var index = truck.parent.getChildIndex(truck);
```

in order to get the index of the `truck` object. Then, you will need to set the index of the objects you want to show above, using this:

```
block.parent.setChildIndex(block, index + 1);
```

Alternatively, you can remove and then re-add an object in order to get it to be above (highest index) of all the other objects on the canvas:

```
var parent = block.parent;
parent.removeChild(block);
parent.addChild(block);
```